# Get number of items in orderByChild equalTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I was checking the firebase docs looking for how to get the number of items saved in my DB according to a query and I looked at this piece of code that has (I think) exactly what I'm looking for, but dont know how to get the numbers of items displayed.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(0.6).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

The console.log should display 2 items as there are 2 dinosaur with that height. So how can I get the number of items displayed to show it on the view?

I tried with console.log(snapshot.key().length); but it displays a wrong number

Comment: Maybe try .lenght after .equalTo(0.6)? Looks like the last part is attaching an event "on child_added".

Comment: @Arg0n not sure how should I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you listen for the `child_added` event, the number of items in your callback will always be `1`. This is great for when you (for example) want to add each item to a list. But it's not great when you want to count the number of items.

For operations that need to handle multiple items, it's easier to listen to the `value` event:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(0.6).on("value", function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
})
```

This snippet also shows the other piece of the puzzle: `DataSnapshot.numChildren()`.

Comment: Finally, thanks for your help, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
var shortDinosaurs = ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(0.6);
console.log(shortDinosaurs.length);
shortDinosaurs.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

Comment: I left out ref, sorry.

Comment: still undefined the first console.log. The second one works well, it displays the keys and if I change it to val(), works well too, it displays two objects. But length no working

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways, the problem is solved above ;)